# How Reorganize Output of Powershell Command?

Tags: powershell, output

How can i reorganizate the otuput, of this powershell command?

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Property Name,StartMode,State -Filter "Name='Fax'"|findstr /r /c:'^[A-Z]'
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name             : Fax
StartMode        : Manual
State            : Stopped
```

OUTPUT Desired:

```
Fax;Manual;Stopped
```

I have to use, set comand? or i can do something else, on command line?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this so that you can save the information in a semi-colon delimited file?

Comment: Yes, i can save output on a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're just doing a semi-colon delimited string... you can create a string from the properties of the object output by `Get-WmiObject` to get your desired output.

Example:

```
PS C:\> $object = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Property Name,StartMode,State -Filter "Name='Fax'"

# Example 1: Concatenating strings
PS C:\> $object.Name+";"+$object.StartMode+";"+$object.State
Fax;Manual;Stopped

# Example 2: Using string joining
PS C:\> [string]::join(';',$object.Name,$object.StartMode,$object.State)
Fax;Manual;Stopped

# Example 3: Using string joining with an array
PS C:\> $array = @($object | % { $_.Name, $_.StartMode, $_.State })
PS C:\> [string]::join(';',$array)
Fax;Manual;Stopped

# Example 4: The join operator
PS C:\> $object.Name,$object.StartMode,$object.State -join ";"
Fax;Manual;Stopped
```

You can read more about the `-join` operator [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx), and more about `[string]::join` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The output it's different: PS C:\> echo $object.Name+";"+$object.StartMode+";"+$object.State+;+Name             : Fax StartMode        : Manual State            : Stopped.StartMode+;+Name             : Fax Start
Mode        : Manual State            : Stopped.State

Comment: @clarkseth Try removing the content after your pipe `|` and it should be fine. You don't need `findstr` if you're just going to join the properties for outputting anyway.